# Will having a cancelled departure stamp in my passport cause problems when I travel?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

Will I have problems entering a country if I have a cancelled departure stamp from my home country?

Will immigration ask questions about it, and what should I do?

Comment: Could you elaborate more about what you mean by a 'void flight stamp'? Perhaps include a photo?

Comment: I already pass the immigration then they already put an exit with the date of flight then suddenly they ask me other documents but since I was not able to provide it they cancelled my flight and they put void stamp

Comment: this is when I will go out from my country for travel in asian country

Comment: Which citizenship do you hold and which country did you enter?

Answer (score 6):

Given that many countries don't supply departure stamps at all, and certainly not for citizens, I'd seriously doubt many customs officials are going to bother checking them all. Mostly they just glance through to see if any places you've been are on the watchlist, whether your name comes up on a criminal records search, and (if applicable) whether your visa is valid.

Used to have a passport with an arrival stamp but no departure stamp, official on departure had forgotten to stamp it. Never caused any trouble elsewhere (though my dad had something similar in the US and it raised a few eyebrows, but that was in combination with a smudged text on his visa, embassy worker had closed the passport before the ink had properly dried).

Of course if there's something raising a red flag and they do dig deeper, they might ask a question or two about inconsistencies like that.